Cannot drop a view due to an unrecognized hive type
I am using Databricks (14.3 LTS, Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)
I have created a view, then I noticed that I need to change its columns, and then I couldn't recreate it with a new schema. Furthermore, I have tried to drop it and create once again, but it didn't help, IU always get the error:
[CANNOT_RECOGNIZE_HIVE_TYPE] Cannot recognize hive type string: "", column: vca_columns. The specified data type for the field cannot be recognized by Spark SQL. Please check the data type of the specified field and ensure that it is a valid Spark SQL data type. Refer to the Spark SQL documentation for a list of valid data types and their format. If the data type is correct, please ensure that you are using a supported version of Spark SQL. SQLSTATE: 429BB, db: mes, table: measurement_cols.
So now I cannot drop or recreate the view. SQL command doesn't work, WEB UI neither.
Did anybody face the issue?
Is there is any option to do a "force" drop of a view?
I didn't find any similar options in the official documentation.
I appreciate any help!
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW hive_metastore.mes.measurement_cols AS
-- Define the schema for the vca_columns column
WITH df_docmsg_parsed AS (
  SELECT
      *,
      from_json(vca_document,
      '
      _AGRADE string,
      _FGRADE string,
      _FRAM string,
      _GLOBAL_MDDB_IDENTIFIER string,
      _GLOBAL_MDDB_MACHINETYPE string,
      _GRADEFAI5A string,
      _GRADEFAI5B string,
      _GRADEFAI8A string,
      _GRADEFAI8B string
      ') AS vca_columns
  FROM hive_metastore.mes.measurement
)
SELECT
    *,
    vca_columns._AGRADE AS _AGRADE,
    vca_columns._FGRADE AS _FGRADE,
    vca_columns._FRAM AS _FRAM,
    vca_columns._GLOBAL_MDDB_IDENTIFIER AS _GLOBAL_MDDB_IDENTIFIER,
    vca_columns._GLOBAL_MDDB_MACHINETYPE AS _GLOBAL_MDDB_MACHINETYPE,
    vca_columns._GRADEFAI5A AS _GRADEFAI5A,
    vca_columns._GRADEFAI5B AS _GRADEFAI5B,
    vca_columns._GRADEFAI8A AS _GRADEFAI8A,
    vca_columns._GRADEFAI8B AS _GRADEFAI8B
FROM df_docmsg_parsed
OPTIONS (DF_IGNOREUNSUPPORTED = true);


Could you please provide your sample table and sample view?

I have tried your code to reproduce your error, but it executed successfully.

So, there is nothing wrong with your code; this error itself indicates that the data type in vca_columns is not supported. Try the following ways:

Try using SQL code to drop the view:

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS hive_metastore.mes.measurement_cols;


If the view is cached, try refreshing the table:

%sql
REFRESH TABLE hive_metastore.mes.measurement_cols;
CLEAR CACHE;


You can also try using the repair command:

MSCK REPAIR TABLE hive_metastore.mes.measurement_cols SYNC METADATA;

Additionally, check the vca_columns data type in your table to see if it is unsupported or not.

@Bogdan Lashkov  Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

hi! Thanks for you support! Looks like this table is now undeletable :D Nothing works, still the same issue. Btw, MSCK REPAIR works only with Unity Catalog.
